# PHP Touch() using time() parameter for the past -any limitation?

Tags: php

When changing a file's datetimestamp from the current system time to the distant past is there a limit with the time() parameter?  With touch(), all the documentation I can see uses the time() parameter which has a future limitation of 100000 seconds:

```
 <?php
 $file_pointer = "gfg.txt";  
 // setting touch time to 5 hours in the past
 $time = time() - 18000;  
 // using touch() function to change the modification 
 // time of a file to current system time
 if (touch($file_pointer, $time)) 
 {
 echo ("$file_pointer modification time has been changed to 5 hours in the past.");
  } 
 else 
 {
 echo ("$file_pointer modification time cannot be changed.");
 }  
 ?>
```

What would be the best approach to change it to 1 year in the past or even 5 years in the past?  Would the following be the most accepted approach and would it work?:

```
 $time = time() - 31536000;// 1 year
 $time = time() - 157680000;// 5 years
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$time = strtotime("5 years ago");
// or
$time = strtotime("-5 years")
```